# Resizing columns not refreshing properly

Tags: c#, datagridview

I made some change, I don't know what, and now when I try to resize columns on my DataGridView it just moves the line the control doesn't redraw properly. Basically parts of the control just don't redraw at all until I do something like move another window over them to force a redraw.

The only thing I can think of is that I tried suspending and resuming layout to fix another issue. It didn't work so I removed those lines of code. Don't see how that could affect it since those lines of code are not even there anymore though?

Not even sure how to debug this further.

Comment: @BVermon, have you considered placing the `Refresh()` such that it is called after after the data has loaded, that way you would not see your columns moving for half a second

Comment: The other thing you could try is, first mark the region for painting using  `.Invalidate()` and then `Update()` which  forces any currently invalid regions to repaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a call to Refresh() the control in its OnColumnDisplayIndexChanged event and that seems to have fixed it.

A strange, but not problematic, side effect is that I can now see the columns moving for a half a second as the application programmatically sets the column widths after loading data. I guess this makes sense, however in the past it would only display after the code had updated the widths. But oh well, that's not a big deal.

Comment: Lmao same. Brains truly are an old computer. Just need some time to process our own questions haha. I would try messing with where the .Refresh() call is made to see if that will effect anything (maybe including multiple, which has saved me some trouble multiple times)